# bsub option confused with job arguments

Tags: command-line-arguments, lsf

I want to submit a job to LSF using the `bsub` command. One of the job argument is "`-P argument_1`". So the overall command looks like

```
bsub -P project_name -n 4 -W 10:00 my_job -P argument_1
```

But `bsub` considers `-P argument_1` as the `project_name` instead of considering as an argument of `my_job`.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried your command in my cluster and it works as expected. Could you provide more details to show why you think that `argument_1` is used as the project name rather than an argument to `my_job`?  e.g., provide the output of `bjobs -l` for your job.

Answer (score 0):

What version of LSF are you using?  You can check by running `lsid`.  Try quoting your command and see if that helps:

```
bsub -P project_name -n 4 -W 10:00 "my_job -P argument_1"
```

Comment: Version of LSF: IBM Platform LSF Advanced 9.1.3.0, Jul 04 2014

Comment: Could you please append the output of `bjobs -l <jobid>` to your question like @Michael Closson suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Use a submission script `script.sh` including `my_job -P placeholder_arg1`. Then use

```
sed 's/placeholder_arg1/argument_1/g' < script.sh | bsub
```

to replace command line argument on-the-fly before submitting the job.